# Parametric access to DBT nested variables in dbt_project.yml

Tags: variables, yaml, dbt

Based on [Nested variables in dbt_project.yml file of dbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168808/nested-variables-in-dbt-project-yml-file-of-dbt)

```
vars:
    env: env_var('DBT_ENVIRONMENT')
    bucket:
        dev: "dev-bucket"
        uat: "uat-bucket"
        ppd: "ppd-bucket"
        prd: "prd-bucket"
```

I would like to access to the bucket name based on the value of the env var `env`.

For example I would reference the `dev` bucket like:

```
{{ var('bucket')['dev'] }}
```

But I want instead to call it parametric based on the var `env` with something similar:

```
{{ var('bucket')[ {{ var('env') }} ] }}
```

It's just that with this I get the following error message:

```
Compilation Error Could not render {{ var('bucket')[ {{ var('env') }} ] }}
```

and I don't know if this is possible to reference with DBT syntax.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be

```
{{ var('bucket')[ env_var('DBT_ENVIRONMENT') ] }}
```

but still I'd prefer to reference directly `var('env')` from the dbt_project.yml, so open to better solutions.